# Excel file from server to client | Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, buffer, xlsx, fs

What I want to do: I have on the server side a file 'test_download.xlsx', and want to send it to the client side so that I can apply XLSX.read() on the retrieved object.

So I tried it this way

Server :

```
let filename = 'test_download.xlsx';
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(filename)
res.json(buffer);
```

Client :

```
file = await axios.get('/dataexplorer/test');
console.log(file);
console.log(XLSX.read(file.data, {type: "buffer"}));
```

First log :

[image]

Second log :

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't match my excel file at all just in terms of sheets (my file has 3 different sheet names)
Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server-side just use:

```js
const filename = 'test_download.xlsx';
// make sure to include the name and the extension of the file in the path
const filepath = 'your/path/to/the/file/test_download.xlsx';
/** filename is optional: 
 * if you don't pass it, the name of the file in the filepath will be used
 * if you pass it the file at hte filepath will be downloaded with the name of `filename`
 */
res.download(filepath, filename);
```

This will return a blob to the client(make sure to include the correct headers for the response type) and then you can just save it or work with it with :

```
file = await axios.get('/dataexplorer/test',{ responseType: "blob"});
const ab = await file.data.arrayBuffer();
XLSX.read(Buffer.from(ab),{type:"buffer"})
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, what is the correct header to use when returning a blob ? I used `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename); res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');` but doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, i've been unclear, with response type header i meant on the client, when you're sending the request to the server, i'm using angular and with that it looks like this:
`this.http.get(\`/api/v1/documents/${doc.id}\`, { responseType: "blob" })`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have a blob in file : data: `Blob {size: 11948, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}` but when i call XLSX.read on file.data i got TypeError: t.replace is not a function. I tried `XLSX.read(await file.data.arrayBuffer(),{type:"array"}` but got Error: Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory

Comment: Blob.arrayBuffer() method returns a promise, you shuld use it like:
`file.data.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => /* do stuff with the buffer */);`
or:
`const buffer = await file.data.arrayBuffer();`

Comment: What I did :  `const buffer = await file.data.arrayBuffer();
    console.log(XLSX.read(buffer,{type:"buffer"}))`  and i still got 
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory`

Comment: That's my fault, the `arrayBuffer()` method returns an instance of ArrayBuffer and not an actual buffer so it should be `const ab = await file.data.arrayBuffer();` and then `XLSX.read(Buffer.from(ab),{type:"buffer"})`. That should work properly

Comment: Thanks Nick ! As I'm on the client side I have `Buffer is not defined` error. I tried to add <script src="https://bundle.run/buffer"></script> and replace Buffer by buffer.Buffer [(method find here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237161/how-can-i-use-node-js-buffer-library-in-client-side-javascript). I think it fixed the Buffer issue but I still have now the same error : `xlsx.full.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory`

Comment: I'm finding hard to understand the logic behind your program, the last things i can say are: a) be sure that the blob it's not corrupted; b) parse the blob in another, more usable, format(not buffer); c) last but not least maybe change your res.download to another method to send a stream instead of a blob. That's all, i would like to help you more but i can't understand where the error is coming from, i'm sorry

Comment: "Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory" was an error due to the file downloading on the server side. Your solution works otherwise thanks !